# Merge two data-frames with only one column different. Need to append that column in the new dataframe. Please check below for detailed view

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Little new  to Python, I am trying to merge two data-frame with columns similar. 2nd data-frame consists of 1 column different need to append that in new data-frame.

[Detailed view of dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJBk3.png)

Code Used :

```
df3 = pd.merge(df,df1[['Id','Value_data']],
               on = 'Id')

df3 = pd.merge(df,df1[['Id','Value_data']],
               on = 'Id', how='outer')
```

Getting Output csv as

```
Unnamed: 0  Id_x    Number_x    Class_x Section_x   Place_x Name_x  Executed_Date_x Version_x   Value   PartDateTime_x  Cycles_x    Id_y    Mumber_y    Class_y Section_y   Place_y Name_y  Executed_Date_y Version_y   Value_data  PartDateTime_y  Cycles_y
```

whereas i dont want _x & _y i wanted the output to be :

```
Id  Number  Class   Section Place   Name    Executed_Date   Version Value Value_data    PartDateTime    Cycles
```

If i use `df2=pd.concat([df,df1],axis=0,ignore_index=True)`
then i will get values in the below mentioned format in all columns except `Value_data`; whereas `Value_data` would be empty column.

```
Id  Number  Class   Section Place   Name    Executed_Date   Version Value Value_data    PartDateTime    Cycles
```

Please help me with a solution for this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think easiest path is to make a temporary df, let's call it df_temp2 , which is a copy of df_2, with renamed column, then append it to df_1

```
df_temp2 = df_2.copy()
df_temp2.columns = ['..','..', .... 'value' ...]
```

then

```
df_total = df_1.append(df_temp2)
```

This provides you a total DataFrame with all the rows of DF_1 and DF_2. 'append()' method supports a few arguments, check the docs for more details.

--- Added --------

One other possible approach is to use `pd.concat()` function, which can work in the same way ad `.append()` method, like this

```
result = pd.concat([df_1, df_temp2])
```

In your case the two approaches would lead to similar performances. You can consider `append()` as a method written on top of `pd.concat()` but it is applied to a DF itself.

Full docs about **concat()** here: [pd.Concat() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: No still same issue persists column Value_data column empty.. & Unnamed: 0 this column is getting added extra after df_total = df_1.append(df_temp2)

Comment: post full code you used so we can help better, just make sure to rename the column you need

Comment: YES! .copy() is mandatory in this case, otherwise, if you make changes to df_temp2 , they will be applied to df_2 too. IF you use .copy() , df_temp2 will be a different separate independent DF.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv('C:/Users/output_2.csv')
df1 pd.read_csv('C:/Users/output_1.csv')
df1_temp=df1[['Id','Cycles','Value_data']].copy()
df3=pd.merge(df,df1_temp,on = ['Id','Cycles'], how='inner')
df3=df3.drop(columns="Unnamed: 0")
df3.to_csv('C:/Users/output.csv')

This worked
```